# assigning a custom destination to popToRootViewController swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, rootviewcontroller

I am using navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) to dismiss my current view to the previous view. My view controller relationship looks like this.

```
VC1->VC2
VC1->VC3
VC3->VC2
```

Whenever the client is in VC2 I want to pop the navigation controller back to VC1. This works fine when the rootviewcontroller is set to VC1. However, when the client uses a segue from VC3 to enter VC2, the rootviewcontroller is set to VC3 and the navigation controller pops to VC3.

I tried to change the rootviewcontroller like this.

```
 // set root view controller
    let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let VC1 = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC1") as! FirstViewController
    appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = VC1
    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

But this actually returns the viewcontroller to the root view controller (VC1) even before the line "navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)" is executed so there is no animation.

Is there any way to set the rootviewcontroller of a navigation controller without presenting the root view controller right away?

Comment: Are you setting new RootViewController everytime while navigating or just pushing in stack ?

Comment: when VC1 goes to VC2, the navigation controller is pushed. However, when VC1 goes to VC3, VC3 is assigned to a new navigation controller (this is bc I wanted a vertical segue of new navigation controller coming up). So when the user takes VC1->VC3->VC2, the root view is VC3, which is the first on the navigation stack.. I am quite lost on how to work this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put `appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = VC1`, the stack of controllers has died, you only have in the stack an alone Controller, therefore you can't apply `popToRootViewController`.

If this is your required navigation, maybe, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32135302/2342915) helps you:
[image]