# popToRootViewController is not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, authentication

I am new to ios development. So please help me to solve this simple issue. The initial screen of my app is login screen. When i am running or time of build login screen showing as expected. But when i press logout button coming to login using "popToRootViewController" storyboard login screen is showing instead of original login screen.[image: Initial Login Screen working with storyboard and viewcontroller]

[image: After logout it is showing this login screen, this is toryboard login screen]

when i press login button navigating to main screen,

```
let mainVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC")
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainVC!, animated: true)
```

In the main screen i have with tab controller with 5 tabs, last tab is Logout, when i press logout the code is below.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                defaults.removeObject(forKey: "isLoggedin")
                defaults.removeObject(forKey: "user")
                defaults.synchronize()
               self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

What i am thinking is viewcontroller code is not getting executed when i press logout and come to login screen. I am not sure why it is working this way. Please let me know  or help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance..

Comment: it is a rootviewcontroller of the app, i am not calling that manually through the code..

Comment: logout button press is which screen?

Comment: can you try "popViewController" instead of "popToRootViewController".

Comment: @HimanshuPatel logout button is there in main screen or mainVC..

Comment: @malli - is this possible to attach your tried code

Comment: Also can you show your code for login button action?

Comment: Please check :-https://stackoverflow.com/a/51095518/6920041
RootViewController only working VC1 to VC2. VC2 in logout press to rootViewController

Comment: @fazeelahamed i tried with popViewController but same issue..

Comment: it is difficult to help you if you don't show the relevant code. To be honest I am still trying to understand why there are 2 login VCs.

Comment: Can you show you'r storyboard? Are you using segues?

Comment: All please check i have updated my question with some code base.

Comment: @Mat only 1 login VC i am using not 2 login VCs, but i am not getting first login screen when i do logout with popViewController is what the issue..

Comment: @fazeelahamed i used segue in my first tab..

Comment: so, when the app loads for the first time, you want the LoginVC to show but then when a user logout you want to show another VC? What is the first VC in your stack? Can you show your storyboard? Can you also edit to show us which VC are you pushing mainVC from?

Answer (score -1):

Is this how you are getting the Storyboard reference and the reference to you'r MainVC?

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let mainVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC") as! MainVC
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainVC, animated: true)
```